# Log time spent between switch a Windows on and off

Tags: windows-7, time, productivity, tracking, cronjob

I want to log the time I spend between switching my PC on and when I switch it off; like have a text file updated with records of each time I switch my PC in the morning and switch it off at the afternoon so by the end of the month I can see how many hours I have been working.

Is there any existing application doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the Uptime Utility

> Microsoft have published a tool called Uptime.exe. It is a simple
>   command line tool that analyses the computer's reliability and
>   availability information. It can work locally or remotely. In its
>   simple form, the tool will display the current system uptime. An
>   advanced option allows you to access more detailed information such as
>   shutdown, reboots, operating system crashes, and Service Pack
>   installation.
>
> Read the following KB for more info and for the download links:
>   [Uptime.exe Tool Allows You to Estimate Server Availability with
>   Windows NT 4.0 SP4 or Higher](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243).
>   To use it, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Download uptime.exe from the above link, and save it to a folder,
>      preferably in one that's in the system's path (such as SYSTEM32).
> 2. Open an elevated Command Prompt window. To open an elevated Command
>      Prompt, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories,
>      right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. You
>      can also type CMD in the search box of the Start menu, and when you
>      see the Command Prompt icon click on it to select it, hold
>      <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
> 3. Navigate to where you've placed the uptime.exe utility.
> 4. Run the `uptime.exe` utility. You can add a /? to the command in order
>      to get more options.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606774/how-to-get-the-uptime-in-windows)

---

In case the previous was an overkill for You, for easier use I advise:
[Uptime Monitor and Power Calculator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uptimepowercalc/)

> Description
>
> Written in C#, this small program is used to log computer uptime and
>   downtime for purposes of calculating power consumption and costs as
>   well as savings, where downtime is considered either standby or
>   hibernate.

---

There is also a software with better design and more advanced GUI, called [up.time](http://www.uptimesoftware.com/).
In the free version, You have a limited amount of functions but it is not defined if uptime monitoring is included. http://www.uptimesoftware.com/overview.php

Answer (score 0):

Get a RaspberryPi and make it ping your windows machine every minute or so, and append every state change to a file (or better a database). How about also pinging your phone, so you know when you left and came back? Or ping your smart-tv so that you can keep track of how often and how long you watched tv.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows "Event Log" (`eventvwr.msc`) has such records, though finding them might be difficult. You can enable system event auditing via `secpol.msc` (or Group Policy), which will write explicit "system booted", "user logged in", "system shut down" entries.